# Is to good to send requests to Service by calling its public functions in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, android-download-manager

I have a Service which its responsibility is to download files from Internet. My Service can download multiple files at the same time.I should be able to send requests to my Service from different classes, e.g., from Activities, Fragments or NotificationManager.

What is the best way to send download requests to the Service?. should I send the data via Intent or it is better to access to the reference of the Service and call one of it's public functions?
Which one is better? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it depends. If all you need to do is give the service some task to perform and you don't want any response from it, then you should just send the info via an intent and forget about it.

If you need to communicate with the service about the download such as progress, download status, and other kinds of stuff like that, you should probably bind to the service (if you're using an activity).

If you're not using an activity and you need to communicate with the service, there's a number of ways you could implement communication. You could use an event interface where the service can send events to whoever cares to listen about its download progress, queues and other things like that. The other party can also send events to the service which might prompt the service to respond with another event or perform some task. This way, you don't keep a reference to a service that can be killed anytime by Android. You'll just know that if you send an event to the service and you don't get a response back, then the service is dead (or it just doesn't want to respond).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use Intents to pass information and not retain the Service reference to call its public methods.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use WorkManager instead of a service. Since services can be terminated by the system for optimization.
ex.

```
     class DownloadWorker(appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters):
          Worker(appContext, workerParams) {
                override fun doWork(): Result {

               // Do the work here--in this case, upload the images.
                  downloadFile()

               // Indicate whether the work finished successfully with the Result
               return Result.success()
            }
          }
```

and you can start any and multiple works with  constraints like network should connected
like this:

```
      /**
       * Constraints
       * Network type is conneted
       */
          mConstraints =new Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build();

          mRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(DownloadWorker.class).setConstraints(mConstraints)
            .build();
WorkManager
.getInstance(myContext)
.enqueue(mRequest)
```

WorkManager makes sure your work run.

For more info check this: [WorkManager]:https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics